# fancybox срабатывает один раз

Tags: fancybox

Есть задача: при нажатии на превью получить видео в модальном окне.

Реализую как указано в коде ниже, но срабатывает только один раз: если закрыть щелчком мыши в пустую область или на крестик и повторно кликнуть на превьюшку, при этом модальное окно запускается без содержимого.

```js
< script type = "text/javascript"
src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js" >
  < /script>

<script type="text/javascript
" src=" / fancybox / jquery.mousewheel - 3.0.4.pack.js ">    </script>

<script type="
text / javascript " src=" / fancybox / jquery.fancybox - 1.3.4.pack.js "></script>
 
<script type="
text / javascript ">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#
content ").fancybox({
        'titlePosition' : 'inside',
        'transitionIn' : 'none',
        'transitionOut' : 'none'
    });
});
</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" media="screen" />


  <link href='css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet' media='screen'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/myowncss.css">
  <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
  <title>potato</title>
</head>

<body>

  <a id="content" href="#potato">
    <img src="/video/logo.png" alt="potato">
  </a>
  <div style="display: none; border: 1px">
    <div id="potato" style="width:800px; height:auto; overflow:auto;">

      <iframe width="800" height="600" src="https://youtu.be/XqXZwgG990I;" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>


      </iframe>
    </div>
  </div>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот набросал 
http://jsfiddle.net/Lejbmeg0/

html

```
<a rel="vd" href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/iErGRJ59JOw?autoplay=1" class="iframe">                                     
<img src="http://cs424523.vk.me/v424523302/3a34/U0qJB6B4hJg.jpg" class="img-frame" alt="" />   
</a>
```

css

```
http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css
```

js

```
http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.js
$(".iframe").fancybox({ 
        padding : 10,
        width : 800,     
        height : 600, 
        'type':'iframe',
        'autoScale':'false'     
    });
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, Ваш ответ навел меня на мысль об использовании старых версий fancybox или неправильном его подключении. Протестировав еще раз свой скрипт на jsfiddle.net, понял, что там он работает с последними версиями файлов...а у меня были указаны не последние.

Answer (score 0):

Если кто столкнётся с такой же проблемой, когда в проекте используется *Fancybox 1.3*, а использовать старую версию *jq* не удаётся.
[Вот](http://mymonkeydo.com/fancybox-not-working-after-second-click/) патч.